# Winsock2 error 10014 on split TCP stream

Tags: c, tcp, winsock2

code first

```
DWORD WINAPI tcp_t(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    SOCKET tcp_client_s = (SOCKET)lpParam;
    struct sockaddr_in tcp_client;
    int tcp_client_len = sizeof(tcp_client), length;
    char req[4096], resp[4096];

    getpeername(tcp_client_s, (struct sockaddr *)&tcp_client, &tcp_client_len);

    cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_SYS, "(%s:%d) TCP thread spawned\n", inet_ntoa(tcp_client.sin_addr), ntohs(tcp_client.sin_port));

    length = get_req_tcp(tcp_client_s, req, tcp_client);

    if(strci(req, "GET /syachi2ds/web/", 0))
    {
        while(!strstr(req, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"))
            length += get_req_tcp(tcp_client_s, req + length, tcp_client);

        length = check_req(req, resp);

        if(length > 0)
            send_resp_tcp(tcp_client_s, resp, length, tcp_client);
    }

    closesocket(tcp_client_s);
    cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_SYS, "(%s:%d) socket closed, closing thread\n", inet_ntoa(tcp_client.sin_addr), ntohs(tcp_client.sin_port));
    ExitThread(0);
}

int get_req_tcp(SOCKET in_s, char *buf, struct sockaddr_in in)
{
    int retval;

    cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_COMM, "(%s:%d) waiting for incoming request...\n", inet_ntoa(in.sin_addr), ntohs(in.sin_port));
    if ( (retval = recv(in_s, buf, 4096, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_ERROR, "(%d) recv() failed\n", WSAGetLastError());
    cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_COMM, "(%s:%d) data received\n", inet_ntoa(in.sin_addr), ntohs(in.sin_port));
    return retval;
}
```

This is part of a larger program I'm writing that does some kind of server emulation. It works good with TCP streams thar are not split into multiple packets, otherwise it gives winsock error 10014 on the first subsequent `recv()` invoked in the while loop.

PS: `strci()` is a custom case-insensitive `strstr()`

PS2: i know there's no check for buffer overflows on req array.

Comment: In case of failure: which value does the first `get_req_tcp()` call (before the loop) return for `length`?

Comment: at this moment cli_log() calls exit(0) if LOG_ERROR is passed as second parameter (i have already in plan to change this behavior)

Comment: Data read from a socket stream is not nul-terminated, so you need to manually add a `'\0'` at the end after each `recv` if you want to use `strstr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10014 is `WSAEFAULT`, which means `recv()` is detecting that "the buf parameter is not completely contained in a valid part of the user address space.".  That makes sense because you have a buffer overflow error in your code.  You have allocated 4096 bytes on the call stack for your `req` buffer.  Each time you call `get_req_tcp()`, you are telling it to read 4096 bytes, even if `req` does not actually have 4096 bytes available to read into.

Each time your loop runs, you are telling `recv()` to read bytes into a new start position within the buffer, but you are not telling `recv()` how many bytes are remaining after that position, so the loop overflows the buffer and will eventually access a memory address that is not on the call stack, causing the `WSAEFAULT` error.

You need to add an extra parameter to `get_req_tcp()` that tells it how many bytes to read.

Try this:

```
DWORD WINAPI tcp_t(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    SOCKET tcp_client_s = (SOCKET)lpParam;
    struct sockaddr_in tcp_client;
    int tcp_client_len = sizeof(tcp_client), length;
    char req[4096], resp[4096];

    getpeername(tcp_client_s, (struct sockaddr *)&tcp_client, &tcp_client_len);

    cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_SYS, "(%s:%d) TCP thread spawned\n", inet_ntoa(tcp_client.sin_addr), ntohs(tcp_client.sin_port));

    length = get_req_tcp(tcp_client_s, req, sizeof(req), tcp_client);
    if (length > 0)
    {
        while (!strstr(req, "\r\n\r\n"))
        {
            retval = get_req_tcp(tcp_client_s, req + length, sizeof(req) - length, tcp_client);
            if (retval < 1)
            {
                length = 0;
                break;
            }
            length += retval;
        }

        if ((length > 0) && (strci(req, "GET /syachi2ds/web/", 0)))
        {
            length = check_req(req, resp);
            if (length > 0)
                send_resp_tcp(tcp_client_s, resp, length, tcp_client);
        }
    }

    closesocket(tcp_client_s);
    cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_SYS, "(%s:%d) socket closed, closing thread\n", inet_ntoa(tcp_client.sin_addr), ntohs(tcp_client.sin_port));

    return 0;
}

int get_req_tcp(SOCKET in_s, char *buf, int buflen, struct sockaddr_in in)
{
    cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_COMM, "(%s:%d) waiting for incoming request...\n", inet_ntoa(in.sin_addr), ntohs(in.sin_port));

    if ((!buf) || (buflen < 1))
    {
        cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_ERROR, "invalid buffer passed for recv()\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int retval = recv(in_s, buf, buflen, 0);

    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_ERROR, "(%d) recv() failed\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if (retval == 0)
    {
        cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_ERROR, "client disconnected\n");
        return 0;
    }

    cli_log(PROTO_TCP, LOG_COMM, "(%s:%d) %d bytes received\n", retval, inet_ntoa(in.sin_addr), ntohs(in.sin_port));

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: FYI, HTTP responses can easily be much larger than 4096 bytes, so you may want to re-think your approach. Use a dynamic-sized buffer instead. Read raw data into the buffer, growing it as needed, and then read line-by-line from the buffer instead of using `strstr()`.

Comment: +1; this was both informative and solved my (rather similar) problem as well.